# Function prototyping in C language

Tags: c, function

Why can't my code run when I am using a function name "div". But when I change it to any name like " divi",it runs.Can someone explained it? Im 1st yr.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 double div(int, int);

 int main(void)
 {
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("The answer is %.2f", div(num1,num2));
 }

 double div(int x, int y)
 {
    double quot;
    quot=((double) x/y);
    return quot;
 }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div

Comment: Learning about indentation would be a really good idea.  Your code as it stands is almost unreadable to most programmers.  Also, you shouldn't put a line break inside a string.

Comment: What did your compiler say?

Comment: Besides, what you posted does not compile at all. Please copy paste the exact code when you're creating a question.

Answer (score 3):

The standard library [already defines a function called `div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div), so you can't use that name for your own function.

Comment: They cannot use the same name for a function *with external linkage* or if they include the header containing the function declaration (`stdlib.h`).  However, they did not include `stdlib.h` (directly or indirectly) and declared `div` with internal linkage (that is, `static`) then that would be ok.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Right.  For a beginner I wanted to keep it simple.  From the standpoint of readability and maintainability it is better to avoid name conflicts with standard library functions, as much as possible.